# Play java 2.5 guice eager loading and stop hook not working

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, typesafe-stack

This code is in app/ folder  :

```
 public class GuiceConfiguration extends AbstractModule {

        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(KafkaConnection.class).asEagerSingleton();
        }
    }


@Singleton
public class KafkaConnection {

    public KafkaConnection(){
        try {
            ServiceUtils.startKafka();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            PlayLoggerUtils.logError("[Global]", this.getClass(), e);
        }

    }

    public KafkaConnection(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle) {
        lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
            PlayLoggerUtils.logDebug("Kafka shutting down", this.getClass());
            ServiceUtils.shutDownKafka();
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });

    }


}
```

In application conf

```
play.module.enabled += "GuiceConfiguration"
```

The class is being initialized only if I call inject in controller. It is not loading at time of application startup. And the stop hook is also not being executed (tried with ctrl+d and just kill without force in production mode).

Comment: I'm not sure: Doesn't Guice need the @Inject annotation at the constructor? The application.conf and the GuiceConfiguration looks good for me.

Comment: If no constructor is annotated with @Inject, guice will take the one without parameters -- so your stop hook is not registered. Besides, what do you mean with 'call inject in controller'?

Comment: With Play Framework version 2.6.x the configuration declaration :
play.module.enabled += "GuiceConfiguration"
should be in conf/reference.conf file

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your class should have only one constructor. If an instance is created with the default constructor, it will definitely not have registered to the application lifecycle.

Further, it is good practice to provide an interface with an implementation. `KafkaConnection` should be an interface which could have multiple implementations (allows you to stub things when necessary).

With respect to the instance not being loaded eagerly, you use `.asEagerSingleton()` in your module, as well as the `@Singleton` annotation. According to the [Guice docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons):

```
                      PRODUCTION    DEVELOPMENT
.asEagerSingleton()   eager         eager
.in(Singleton.class)  eager         lazy
.in(Scopes.SINGLETON) eager         lazy
@Singleton            eager         lazy
```

@Singleton should be loaded lazily in Development mode. Although in production mode, it should be loaded eagerly.

So a working implementation (also on your dev environment) could look something like this:

```
public class GuiceConfiguration extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(KafkaConnection.class).to(DefaultKafkaConnection.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}

public interface KafkaConnection {}

// No annotation
public class DefaultKafkaConnection implements KafkaConnection {

    // No default constructor, but the ApplicationLifecycle needs
    // to be injected
    @Inject
    public KafkaConnection(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle) {
        try {
            ServiceUtils.startKafka();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            PlayLoggerUtils.logError("[Global]", this.getClass(), e);
        }
        lifecycle.addStopHook(() -> {
            PlayLoggerUtils.logDebug("Kafka shutting down", this.getClass());
            ServiceUtils.shutDownKafka();
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: stop hook is working but still its not eagerloading both in dev and production